# How to use code igniter in ubuntu web server?

Tags: codeigniter, ubuntu, webserver

I have a working ubuntu web server made by myself. PHP, mysql and every thing is working well for websites that are created without codeigniter. The thing is I have a web site that uses the codeigniter frame work. but I don't know how to configure my web server to work with codeigniter.

When i go to localhost keeping the default files browser is showing the codeigniter welcome message.

When I remove the application folder and paste my application folder that is having my php app it is showing an error saying:

> Warning: require(../application/config/constants.php): failed to open
>   stream: Permission denied in
>   /opt/share/php/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 64
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '../application/config/constants.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/share/php/system:/usr/share/php') in
>   /opt/share/php/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 64

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Jeemusu - yes when i go to localhost keeping the default files browser is showing the codeigniter wellcome message. but when i remove the application folder and paste my application folder that is having my php app it is showing an error saying
Warning: require(../application/config/constants.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/share/php/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 64

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../application/config/constants.php' (include_path='.:/opt/share/php/system:/usr/share/php') in /opt/share/php/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 64

Comment: Thats the kind of important information you should include with your question :P  Are the folders and files permissions set correctly? It seems codeigniter is having permission troubles reading your folders/files.

Comment: @Jeemusu -  :) actually i don't know much about these server configurations so i just follow this guild and did almost every thing in it. but stil i'm gettign this error :(
http://askubuntu.com/questions/25446/how-to-install-codeigniter

Comment: You received the error because the file `/application/config/constants.php` has no read permissions, so codeigniter can't open it. It is likely all your files/folders in your application folder have no read permissions set.

Comment: may i give chmod 777 for every thing ?

Comment: I would be weary of giving 777, you don't need to make all your files writable or executable by everyone. Something like chmod 644 would be better. you can use the -r operator to make it recursive (affect subfolders/files).

Comment: I just checked giving 777 for every thing and restarted the apache server. but still error is same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40549/discussion-between-yasitha-and-jeemusu)